# Why Aren't My Values Showing Up In My Sqlite Database When Imported From Tkinter In Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

Its Not Giving Any Errors Just Not Showing Up If it seems a little choppy sorry been getting frustrated but literally everything works no errors at all it even enters the camper id but no name someone please help, thank you, and dont down this please been getting allot of strikes even though most of the people dont actually read the code  [FIXED]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *
#creating screen
page = tkinter.Tk()
#naming screen
page.title('Camp Sign-up')
#setting screen size
page.geometry("1000x500")
#creating text
Title = tkinter.Label(page, text='Registration', font=('arial') ).pack()

FullName = tkinter.Label(page, text='Full Name:', font=('arial')).place(x=110, y=50)
full = StringVar()
FullNameValue = Entry(page, textvar=full, width=25,).place(x=200, y=53)



CamperID = random.randint(100000, 1000000)

#Database



conn = sqlite3.connect('YouthCamp.db')
c = conn.cursor()
def createtable():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Registration (
        CampID INT,
        full TEXT,
        )""")

try:
    createtable()
except:
    sqlite3.OperationalError

#button
def buttonclick():
    #heres where you lnk where you want your info to go
    FullNameValu= full.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('YouthCamp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Registration(CampID, full)VALUES(?, ?)",(CamperID, FullNameValu))
    conn.commit()


#button
work = Button(page, text='Submit', width=10, height=2, bg='lightgrey', 
command=buttonclick()).place(x=475, y=450)

#heres where you execute your close files commands
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
#ending code never put this above anything
page.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buttonclick()` run as soon as you start the program cause have done this way `command=buttonclick()` which suppose to be `command=buttonclick`. Also your creation of your database is not good have changed that and refactor your all code.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *





# THIS IS CREATING DATABASE
conn = sqlite3.connect('YouthCamp.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Registration (CampID INT, full TEXT)""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()


#button
def buttonclick():
    #heres where you lnk where you want your info to go
    FullNameValu= full.get()
    # generating the camp id
    CamperID = random.randint(100000, 1000000)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('YouthCamp.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Registration(CampID, full)VALUES(?, ?)",(CamperID, FullNameValu))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    print("records inserted")




#creating screen
page = tkinter.Tk()
#naming screen
page.title('Camp Sign-up')
#setting screen size
page.geometry("1000x500")
#creating text
Title = tkinter.Label(page, text='Registration', font=('arial') )
Title.pack()

FullName = tkinter.Label(page, text='Full Name:', font=('arial'))
FullName.place(x=110, y=50)

full = StringVar()
FullNameValue = Entry(page, textvar=full, width=25,)
FullNameValue.place(x=200, y=53)

#button
work = Button(page, text='Submit', width=10, height=2, bg='lightgrey',
command=buttonclick).place(x=475, y=450)



page.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you honestly you just saved me months of work its because i was using buttonclick() and it was doing it imidiently on start up thank you

Comment: @Jonah.Jackson accept answer if solves your question .

Comment: The green check? Done. Definitely a help